# Using CALL, RET in assembly x86

Tags: assembly, x86

Consider the following simple assembly code which uses `push`, `pop` and `call`

```
CDSEG SEGMENT
MAIN PROC FAR
    ASSUME CS:CDSEG,DS:DTSEG
    MOV AX,DTSEG
    MOV DS,AX

    MOV AX,1010H        ; (1)
    PUSH AX             ; (2)
    CALL FOO            ; (3)
    ADD AX,2            ; (7)
MAIN ENDP   
FOO PROC   
    POP AX              ; (4)
    ADD AX,1            ; (5)
    RET                 ; (6)
FOO ENDP
END MAIN
```

What I expect, is to see

```
(1) ax = 1010h, stack=????
(2) ax = 1010h, stack=1010h
(3) 
(4) ax = 1010h, stack=????
(5) ax = 1011h
(6)
(7) ax = 1012h
```

but, the emulator shows

```
(1) ax = 1010h, stack=????
(2) ax = 1010h, stack=1010h
(3) 
(4) ax = 000Ch, stack=????
(5) ax = 000Dh
(6) The control never goes back to the main proc
(7) ???
```

What is the fault?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`CALL` pushes the return address on the stack, which is what allows `RET` to return to that address. When you `POP AX` in `FOO` you're popping the return address off the stack. The value you `PUSH`ed before the `CALL` is not at the top of the stack when you enter `FOO`, but rather at `[SP+2]`.

Comment: To expand on this a little bit, procedures don't normally push values of the stack, but access them via a stack frame (using the `bp` register, and it needs to manually be set up) or without a stack frame, directly using `sp`. A stack frame is useful if you also have locals on the stack on your function.

Comment: To put it simple: You messed up the stack! Because you pop'ed the return address of the call, the `PROC` returns to nowhere/somewhere.

Comment: @MicroVirus to clarify - you mean that (called) procedures don't normally _pop_ values off the stack?

Comment: @spamove correct, sorry for the confusion